# SQL: exporting to XML reformats numeric data to scientific notation

Tags: sql, xml

I have inherited some SQL code at work. I only really know basic SQL so apologies if this is trivial.

The code exports a SQL query to XML. The numeric fields in the SQL table seem fine, but when exported to XML they are converted to exponent notation: e.g. 5.600000000000000e+001 where it should be 56. They should all be integers, so I presume there is a way to stipulate that. Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
WITH INSTs AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT INST_CODE CODE, 
            INST_NAME name,  
            INST_REGION region,
        FROM dbo.Y4CONT_OUTDATA),
CONTs AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT INST_CODE,
            CONT_ID,
            CONT_CATEGORY
        FROM dbo.Y4CONT_OUTDATA)
SELECT CODE,
        name,
        region,
        majorityMode,
        (SELECT CONT_ID, CONT_Category,
                (SELECT FT_HEADCOUNT FT_Headcount,
                        PT_HEADCOUNT PT_Headcount,
                        TOTAL_HEADCOUNT total_Headcount                     
                    FROM dbo.Y4CONT_OUTDATA d
                    WHERE CODE = d.INST_CODE
                        AND ct.CONT_ID = d.CONT_ID
                        AND ct.CONT_CATEGORY = d.CONT_CATEGORY
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) [*]
            FROM CONTs ct
            WHERE CODE = ct.INST_CODE
                AND CONT_ID = ct.CONT_ID
                AND CONT_CATEGORY = ct.CONT_CATEGORY
            FOR XML PATH('CONT'), root('CONTData'), TYPE) [*]
    FROM INSTs
    --Wrapping element for each INST
    FOR XML PATH ('INST'), 
--Wrapping element for the whole .XML
root('PUB2019CONTData')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns in question probably aren't of an integer type. Try to convert them to an `integer` or (`bigint` if needed).

```
convert(integer, <column name>)
```